# Intuitive examples to illustrate that pairwise independence does not imply independence

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, independence

I'm reading about independence from a lecture [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf).

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space.

**Definition 3.7.** Let $\left\{\mathcal{G}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{G}_n\right\}$ be a finite collection of sub- $\sigma$-fields of $\mathcal{F}$. This collection is independent if
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_n\right), \quad \forall A_1 \in \mathcal{G}_1, \ldots, A_n \in \mathcal{G}_n
$$

A finite collection of events $\left\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\right\}$ is declared to be independent if $\left\{\sigma\left(A_1\right), \ldots, \sigma\left(A_n\right)\right\}$ is independent.

**Lemma:** The following statements are equivalent

- **S1**: $\left\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\right\}$ is independent.
- **S2**: $\mathbb{P}\left(A_1^* \cap \ldots \cap A_n^*\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_1^*\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_n^*\right)$ where $A_i^* \in \{A_i, A_i^c\}$ for $i \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$.
- **S3**: $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{j \in S} A_j\right)=\prod_{j \in S} \mathbb{P}\left(A_j\right), \quad \forall S \subset\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

**Remark:**

- **R1**: for $n>2$, $\mathbb{P}\left(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_n\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_n\right)$ does **not suffice** to guarantee independence of the whole collection of events.
- **R2**: pairwise independence (i.e., $\mathbb{P}\left(A_j \cap A_k\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A_j\right) \mathbb{P}\left(A_k\right)$ for every $\left.j \neq k\right)$ is **not enough** to ensure the independence of the whole collection.

---

**My questions:**

1. Could you have a check on my below proof?
2. Could you give some examples to illustrate the remarks **R1** and **R2**? Wikipedia provides an [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Pairwise_and_mutual_independence) for **R2**, but it is just a Venn diagram with probabilities and thus not intuitive.

**Proof of Lemma:** We have [**S1** $\iff$ **S2**] and [**S1** $\implies$ **S3**] are clear. Let's prove [**S3** $\implies$ **S2**]. WLOG, we assume

- $A_i^* = A_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots, p$.
- $A_i^* = A_i^c$ for all $i=p+1, \ldots, n$.

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(A_1^* \cap \ldots \cap A_{p+1}^*\right)
&= \mathbb{P}\left(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{p}\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{p} \cap A_{p+1}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_p\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_{p}\right) \cdot  \mathbb{P}\left(A_{p+1}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_{p}\right) \cdot [1-\mathbb{P}\left(A_{p+1}\right)] \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(A_1\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_{p}\right) \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(A^c_{p+1}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(A_1^*\right) \cdots \mathbb{P}\left(A_{p+1}^*\right).
\end{align}
$$

The proof is completed by repeating above procedure.